# Replace a string with a variable

Tags: php, phpexcel

Can anyone help me with the code below? I need to replace hard-coded values with variables.

PHP Code:

```php
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0) 
  ->setCellValue('A1', 'John') 
  ->setCellValue('B1', 'Doe') 
  ->setCellValue('C1', '888-123-456');
```

i.e. 'A1' will become &Cell and 'John' will become `&name`.

Comment: so um `.. setCellValue('A1', $name).. `

Comment: [PHP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) is maybe a good place to start.

Comment: as well as editing how about responding to the comments

Comment: Sorry, A1 should be variable too. I tried "setCellValue($cell, $name) and that casued the excel cannot be opened.

Comment: well that is valid syntax, so something else is going on

Comment: @JimW Maybe do you intend excel variable names? Or what?

Comment: save the file, dont launch it, open with text editor, i bet you find php errors in it

Comment: It seems the problem is caused by &#65279 is added while generating the value of $cell.